# Using Custom png Image for Tab Bar

Tags: ios, uitabbarcontroller

I've created two custom png images that I want to use on my UI Tab Bar Controller. Both images are 29 x 29 pixels, which I believe is the right size for this purpose. I've added the files to the project, and referenced them from the Tab Bar. But when I run the app, they don't display.

The files are called cube.png and sphere.png. Here are screen shots to illustrate what i've done.

[image][image]

But when I run it, I get only this (no custom images)

[image]

How do I correct this?

Comment: Read the docs for `UITabBarItem initWithTitle:image:tag:` for an explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tab bar images only support transparent images in which the object should be drawn only in white color. If it contains any color,it will automatically converted to white. So use the appropriate image. You will get the result. For reference, you can find some of these [here](https://www.iconfinder.com/)